# Implement FromIterator correctly to collect values from iter into my struct

Tags: rust, struct, actix-web

I want to `iter` over my user and collect specific values based on my `Query`. My `actix-web` endpoint should return the `key` and collected `values` in my `IsumisData` struct. Do I need to implement `FromIterator` or is there an easier solution?

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, ToSchema, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct IsumisData {
    /// Device's MAC address.
    #[schema(example = "")]
    pub key: String,
    /// Data from a device.
    #[schema(value_type = Object, 
        example = "{ token: 2a256356, change: new, data: [ { dns: , mac: , src: , dst: } ] }",
    )]
    pub value: Value
}
```

```rust
impl FromIterator<Vec<(&String, &Value)>> for IsumisData {
    fn from_iter<I: IntoIterator<Item=Vec<(&String, &Value)>>>(iter: I) -> Self {
        // I don't know what I should implement here
    }
}
```

```rust
pub fn filter(search: Query<SearchParams>, id: &str) -> Vec<IsumisData> {
    let user: IsumisData = get_user(id).unwrap();
    
    // returns Vec<(&String, &Value)>
    user.value
        .as_object()
        .unwrap()
        .iter()
        .filter(|(key, value)| { 
            key
                .contains(&search.value.to_lowercase())
            })
        .collect::<Vec<IsumisData>>()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how `FromIter` works. As it's [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html) says:

> By implementing `FromIterator` for a type, you define how it will be created from an iterator. This is common for types which describe a collection of some kind.

But your `IsumisData` is not a collection. It just holds some value and you actually want to return from `filter` a **collection of IsumisData** (`Vec<IsumisData>`). So you should not implement `FromIterator` for it, but rather somehow [map](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) your values to `IsumisData`. For example:

```rust
pub fn filter(search: Query<SearchParams>, id: &str) -> Vec<IsumisData> {
    let user: IsumisData = get_user(id).unwrap();
    
    // returns Vec<(&String, &Value)>
    user.value
        .as_object()
        .unwrap()
        .iter()
        .filter(|(key, value)| { 
            key.contains(&search.value.to_lowercase())
         })
        .map(|(key, value)| {
            // I cloned here, because key and value are references.
            // Maybe you want to instead call into_iter to produce owned values.
            IsumisData {key: key.clone(), value: value.clone()}
         })
        .collect()
}
```